# AngularJS: Controller changes not reflected in html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have html code as:

```html
<div ng-controller="LoginController as vm">
    <ul ng-if="vm.user_info">
        <li><a href="/+login">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And controller code as

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('site.authentication.controllers')
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

  LoginController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Authentication'];

  function LoginController($location, $scope, Authentication) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.login = login;
    vm.user_info = true;
    
    function login() {
      promise = Authentication.login(vm.email, vm.password);
      vm.user_info = false;
    }
})();
```

[Edit]Adding Login called code:

```html
<form role="form" ng-submit="vm.login()">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="error" ng-bind="error"></div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login__email" ng-model="vm.email" placeholder="ex. john@example.com" />        
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login__password" ng-model="vm.password" placeholder="ex. thisisnotgoogleplus" />      
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Login link is shown on pre-login html and on login "vm.user_info" is set to false, but is not working and still Login link is shown after login.

Let us know if any issues in above.

Comment: When is vm.login called?

Comment: Can you share how you call `login` function?

Comment: Also `'use static';` - do you mean `'use strict'` ?

Comment: Added where login is called in question. Call is going perfectly in login() function, checked that with with debug points. Not sure why its not reflected in html

Comment: I guess you have not initialized vm.email and vm.password. Is that case?

Answer (score 1):

**This is the alternate solution.**

Use $timeout on vm.user_info.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('site.authentication.controllers')
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

  LoginController.$inject = ['$location', '$scope', 'Authentication'];

  function LoginController($location, $timeout, $scope, Authentication) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.login = login;
    vm.user_info = true;

    function login() {
      promise = Authentication.login(vm.email, vm.password);
      $timeout(function(){
          vm.user_info = false;
      }, 100)
    }
})();
```